# UIImageView causes lag first time they are displayed

Tags: iphone, caching, uiview, uiimageview

I have a couple of UIViews with UIImageViews on them. When I display a view *the first time*, there is a noticeable lag (0.5 second or so) before it is shown. When shown again everything works.

I have managed to work around this by adding all views and then removing them. Like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addAndRemoveAllViews) 
                       withObject:nil 
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The function loops over all views and `[addSubview:view]` followed by `[view removeFromSuperview]`. This seems to trigger the images to load while not being shown.

**Questions:**

1. This all feels like a workaround to me. Is there a better approach to handle these types of things?
2. Is it possible to get a callback or something when it's completed? I want to run an animation when done.

**Update:**

Images are created from `NSData` like this:

```
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:rawData]];
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems very likely the image is larger than the image view.  If possible shrink it down to the size the image view needs.

The initial delay is loading the image from storage, after that you are using a cached version which is why it is faster.

Comment: Thanks. See my update regarding image construction from NSData. Do I have to do anything with the UIImageViews after this? You mention shrinking the size of the UIImageView?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd - imageWithData should not be caching.  Also, I was talking about making the image itself smaller (so that it took less time to load), not making the ImageView smaller.  You may want to try using the TimeProfiler instrument while the image loads to see if the system is doing anything else.

Comment: Possibly related: I'm sometimes getting memory warnings during this. The views contains several images at 1024x768. But the allocation/memory instrument only tells me I'm using 8-10MB (iPad device). I don't understand why i get memory warnings when I'm only using 10MB of RAM. Could this be related?

Comment: Very likely it is related, 1024x768 in memory ends up being a fair bit of memory.  It's better to also have smaller thumbnail versions of the images (if they are not being displayed at 1024x768), or to load fewer at once and load them in as the user moves between them (preparing no more than one to either side of the visible image)

Comment: Nope, I fixed the memory problem. Problem still persists. I simply have to add the ImageViews to an active View first for them to be snappy.